# Oracle Apex 5.0 Remove Topbar

Tags: menu, oracle-apex

I am using the apex 5.0 slate theme with a menu and a top bar.

I would like to keep the menu, but remove the top bar so I can create a different page header.

Is it possible without breaking the menu?[image]
Dont mind the read arrow, It's the top bar with the text "Universal Theme Testing" I want to remove and replace with a custom header.

Comment: Why is the red arrow pointing at Theme Roller? Do you want to Remove the Universal Theme Testing ... Log Out header?

Comment: It's just a picture I found. I used it to show how the default template looked.

Comment: Where do you want to put the menu hamburger, if no top bar?

Comment: Same place as now.

Comment: What sort of page header do you want instead?  Is it just a matter of styling what is already there?